# Queryset object has no attribute _default_manager

Tags: python, django

This is my models.py

```
class PdfParsed(models.Model):
user=models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
pdf_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
status = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

this is my views.py

```
class pdfListView(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
model = PdfParsed.objects.filter(user_id=6)
login_url = '/login/'
context_object_name = 'pdfparsed_list'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    data = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    aa=os.listdir('media/pdfs')
    data['pdf_parsed'] = sum('.pdf' in s for s in aa)
    return data
```

what i wanted to achieve from above code is to print pdfs that are uploaded with respect to user here for testing purpose i used number 6 but its not working it is showing this error:

```
  File "/home/ideas/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/list.py", line 33, in get_queryset
queryset = self.model._default_manager.all()
AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute '_default_manager'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this in your code:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return super().get_queryset().filter(user_id=self.request.user.id)
```

and keep model = PdfParsed